How to reference data added to the end of position independent shellcode in Windows x86
I have a C program that parses the PEB and gets kernel32.dll and then with a custom GetProcAddress it gets the address to LoadLibrary. After that I get the address of MessageBoxA. My goal is to provide the message to print at the end of the shellcode and then reference it and use that as the message to appear in the message box.
What my project currently looks like:
#include <windows.h>

typedef HMODULE(WINAPI* LoadLibraryA_ptr)(LPCSTR);
typedef INT(WINAPI* MessageBoxA_ptr)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPSTR, UINT);

__declspec(naked) void start_func() { __asm { jmp code_func } };

PVOID get_module_address(BYTE* mod){...}
PVOID get_function_address(HMODULE mod, BYTE* func){...}

void code_func(){
    BYTE kernel32_string[] = {'k', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'e', 'l', '3', '2', '.', 'd', 'l', 'l', '\0'};
    BYTE loadlibrary_string[] = {'l', 'o', 'a', 'd', 'l', 'i', 'b', 'r', 'a', 'r', 'y', '\0'};
    BYTE user32_string[] = {'u', 's', 'e', 'r', '3', '2', '.', 'd', 'l', 'l', '\0' };
    BYTE messagebox_string[] = {'m', 'e', 's', 's', 'a', 'g', 'e', 'b', 'o', 'x', 'a', '\0'};

    HMODULE kmod = get_module_address(kernel32_string);
    LoadLibraryA_ptr LoadLibraryA = get_function_address(kmod, loadlibrary_string);

    HMODULE umod = LoadLibraryA(user32_string);
    MessageBoxA_ptr MessageBoxA = get_function_address(umod, messagebox_string);

    MessageBoxA(NULL, messagebox_string, messagebox_string, MB_OK);
}

This is built inside Visual Studio with the following compiler options:
C/C++ -> Optimization -> /O1, /Ob2, /Oi, /Os, /Oy-, /GL
C/C++ -> Code Generation -> /MT, /GS-, /Gy
Linker -> General -> /INCREMENTAL:NO

After it compiles I extract the shellcode and run it inside of a project that just allocates RWX memory, copies this into the buffer and then calls it.
I have tried adding a function at the end of the code_func() however it either gets removed or inlined due to the compiler options. And if I don't call the function it doesn't get compiled into the final shellcode.
The end goal is to have a way to reference somewhere else that is included with this generated shellcode that contains a string. For example at the end of this function could be:
char buffer[100] = {'b', 'u', 'f', 'f', 'e', 'r', '\0'};

Then inside of the call to MessageBoxA instead of referencing messagebox_string it could reference this buffer that can be populated outside of this. So open with a Python script and search for buffer and then replace it.

Write it in assembly and I'll start answering questions on it. This methodology of twisting the compiler round to get it to emit code that it wouldn't normally be able to emit is not good for understanding things.

And it's unclear if you get to MessageBoxA at all (from your test environment). When you look at the generated code, do you see the jmp instruction at the begining?

@ixe013 Yes the jmp is at the beginning.

And if you follow the jmp, do you reach the call to MessageBoxA? Your question is unclear. Is it a code generation issue or is it about passing a string to the shellcode for it to display?

I forgot to include two functions. I kept the code out for readability, they do as the function name says. After the jmp it goes to code_func(). Then it executes all the code and message box appears with the strings. The idea is to have this program or another program append data to the end of this shellcode (once compiled) that the message box would print.
